# Horizontally misaligned labels in xy package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, xy-pic, xymatrix

I have answered to a this question, 
[Long arrows in a commutative diagram with transform canvas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547508/long-arrows-in-a-commutative-diagram-with-transform-canvas/547526#547526)
with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}
\labelmargin-{1pt}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=1.5cm@C=2cm{
 A \ar@<.5ex>[r]^{f} \ar@<.5ex>[d]^{g}& \ar@<.5ex>[l]^{h} B\ar@<.5ex>[dl]\\
 C \ar@<.5ex>[u]^{r} \ar@<.5ex>[ur] & 
 }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why are `r` and `g` labels not well aligned horizontally, like vertical labels?

Comment: do you mean horizontally or vertically? your orange line is drawn at a strange place, below the baseline, if you draw the baseline it looks natural to me `rg` you expect the tail of the g to be below the r surely?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Very kind David Before I have used the translator. Yes you're right: I expect the tail of the g to be below the r. If you want to change my unclear question you're welcome always or welcome.

Comment: To align the `r` and `g`, I would enter the `r` as `{r\vphantom{g}}` to raise the `r`.  Although the depth of the `g` could be removed by `\smash[b]{g}`, that would move it lower, and it already looks closer to the bottom than to the top.  (Not tested.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `\mathstrut in either label, so the alignment is the same independently of the letters used.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix@R=1.5cm@C=2cm{
 A \ar@<.5ex>[r]^{f} \ar@<.5ex>[d]^{\mathstrut g}& \ar@<.5ex>[l]^{h} B\ar@<.5ex>[dl]\\
 C \ar@<.5ex>[u]^{\mathstrut r} \ar@<.5ex>[ur] &
 }

\end{document}
```

[image: picture]

The same with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
 A \arrow[r,shift left=0.5ex,"f"] \arrow[d,shift left=0.5ex,"\mathstrut g"] &
 B \arrow[l,shift left=0.5ex,"h"] \arrow[dl,shift left=0.5ex] \\
 C \arrow[u,shift left=0.5ex,"\mathstrut r"] \arrow[ur,shift left=0.5ex] 
 \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As from the suggestion of the very nice user @barbara beeton, I have added your solutions (by your comment):

**1.** using `\vphantom`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}
\labelmargin-{1pt}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=1.5cm@C=2cm{
 A \ar@<.5ex>[r]^{f} \ar@<.5ex>[d]^{g}& \ar@<.5ex>[l]^{h} B\ar@<.5ex>[dl]\\
 C \ar@<.5ex>[u]^{r\vphantom{g}} \ar@<.5ex>[ur] & 
 }
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2.** or using `\smash[b]{g}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}
\labelmargin-{1pt}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=1.5cm@C=2cm{
 A \ar@<.5ex>[r]^{f} \ar@<.5ex>[d]^{\smash[b]{g}}& \ar@<.5ex>[l]^{h} B\ar@<.5ex>[dl]\\
 C \ar@<.5ex>[u]^{r} \ar@<.5ex>[ur] & 
 }
\end{document}
```

[image]